# Force Function Example Confusion

Tags: r

I'm trying to wrap my head around the R scoping rules, and I'm having trouble understanding the force function's example in the R documentation

```
f <- function(y) function() y
lf <- vector("list", 5)
for (i in seq_along(lf)) lf[[i]] <- f(i)
lf[[1]]()  # returns 5

g <- function(y) { force(y); function() y }
lg <- vector("list", 5)
for (i in seq_along(lg)) lg[[i]] <- g(i)
lg[[1]]()  # returns 1
```

Why does

```
lf[[1]]()
```

return 5 instead of 1?

I have a basic understanding of scoping rules from Hadley's advance R but I can't figure out how it applies here

Comment: You might also try, in the first example, doing `i <- 42` before `lf[[1]]()`. Basically `f` does not receive the value of `i` just a promise to get the value of `i` when requested. In this case, the request does not come until the function call / result print.

Comment: Ok, if I understand this correctly, it's because y is never actually evaluated until you call the anonymous function inside f with lf[[1]](), right?  And then it evaluates y with the value of i that's in the global environment?

Comment: Correct. Which is why `force(y)` is equivalent to `y` (as is stated in the Advanced R Book). From a "what does this code do?" standpoint, it's better to use `force(y)`. But you could replace `force(y)` with `y` and get the same result.